# Fechar somente uma Janela

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Criei uma janela `JanelaUm`, toda vez que clico em `button` essa janela é exibida.

no `code-behind` da `JanelaUm` tenho o evento `window_KeyDown` com o seguinte código:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    this.Close();
```

Porém se o usuário clicar 5 vezes no `button` para exibir a `JanelaUm`, ao fechar utilizando a tecla `esc` fechará as 5 janelas, e não apenas uma.

Alguém teria uma ideia de como fazer para fechar somente uma? e as outras 4 continuarem abertas?

Comment: Como você cria e faz *display* das janelas?

Comment: `JanelaUm JUm = new JanelaUm(); JUm.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Nesse `form`, tu não tem nenhum botão que faça um cancelar?

Comment: Não, somente o botão do próprio `form`.

Comment: eu não consegui reproduzir o problema, se puder, poste mais código do seu exemplo, usa o git pra fazer upload do projeto se possível.

Comment: Não percebo como consegue abrir 5 janelas se você está utilizando `ShowDialog()`? Ao abrir a primeira o *focus* fica nela e você não pode mais aceder à janela inicial enquanto não fechar a que foi aberta.

Comment: Pois é, errei é somente `Show();`

Comment: A resposta do @LucasMotta, resolveu o problema, está fechando somente a janela ativa, as outras continuam abertas.

Comment: Acho isso estranho porque só a janela ativa deveria receber a *key*. Só por curiosidade, onde(*event*) é que você está testando a *key*?

Comment: e no evento `private void window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
   if (e.Key == Key.Escape && this.IsActive)
        this.Close();
```